# Spring cloud data flow UI import jar without http url

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am using PCF and try to bulk /single import  application using http url and found network is blocking extrnal http, is there option to upload my task jar without adding into http ?

Following url i am try to import

http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor/Celsius.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor-Celsius.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.stream-apps-kafka-10-maven

http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor/Celsius.SR3/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor-Celsius.SR3.stream-apps-rabbit-maven
[image: ta]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!

The HTTP URLs that we publish are nothing but a property file with key/value pairs of out-of-the-box application coordinates. You could download the file in your laptop, and use the 3rd choice from the page *"Bulk import application coordinates from a property file."*. Alternatively, from the same page, you could copy + paste the k/v pairs in the *"Apps as Properties"* text-area. These two options would allow the registration of application coordinates in SCDF's App registry.

However, at runtime, these applications will be resolved, downloaded, and deployed (by SCDF) as part of the stream/task deployments. That would mean, in a restricted environment, you may still run into the same connectivity problem.

For that reason, we have different other options in PCF to host/resolve application artifacts — see [ref. docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-cloudfoundry-app-resolution-options). The [SCDF App Tool](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/scdf-app-tool) is typically preferred by PCF customers.